# Adding Unit tests for Cruise Control

Tags: nunit, cruisecontrol.net

I'm trying to add my nunit tests to my cruisecontrol ccnet.config when build is forced on the dashboard, it opens up Nunit on my machine and gives me an error saying error in command line, where am i going wrong?

```xml
    <nunit>
    <path>C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit.exe</path>
    <assemblies>
      <assembly>C:\Users\computeruser\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebCrawlerMVC\WebCrawlerMVC.Tests\bin\Debug\nunit.framework.dll</assembly>
      <assembly>>C:\Users\computeruser\Documents\Visual Studio 2010\Projects\WebCrawlerMVC\WebCrawlerMVC.Tests\bin\Debug\WebCrawlerMVC.Tests.dll</assembly>
    </assemblies>
    <excludedCategories>
      <excludedCategory>LongRunning</excludedCategory>
    </excludedCategories>
  </nunit>
```

is there an easier or better method to take than above?

Comment: I realise i might need to use C:\Program Files (x86)\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit-console.exe if i change the path to this, it gives me an error saying nunit has stopped working.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

try using the **nunit-console.exe** application like this:

```xml
<nunit>
      <path>"C:\Program Files\NUnit 2.6.2\bin\nunit-console.exe"</path>
      ...
</nunit>
```

Comment: I have tried this and it still gives  Problem Signature 09: System.ArgumentException and the program stops working

Comment: okay, silly syntax error on my part, wasn't anything to do with this. accepted and upvoted, thank you.